# Saving from Illustrator to PNG in 300ppi

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, export, ppi

I have problem with illustrator. I wanna made T-shirt design for Printify they recommend *.JPG or *PNG with 4500x5700px size.

I don't know how good quality will be if I made image in PS with 300ppi, so I did image in Ai . And here is problem I setup document raster effect settings to 300ppi, my Artboard is 4500x5700, but when I export image via "Save for web" I will get 4500x5700px image but 72ppi (I open it in PS to check it).

When I use Export via as - "Export as..." I got 300ppi but 18750x23750px what is way too big.
When I use Export via - "Export for screens" I sitll got 4500x5700px but 72ppi

I understand that Vector graphic is diffrent than raster one, and rules for both are different too.

Also re-sizing 18750x23750px to 4500x5700 in PS is option too bot for that I don't need Ai, I can create image directly in PS for that.

Please explain and guide me how I can get size I want and ppi i want in Ai after exporting.

Comment: Ah, yes a pixel is not a unit.

Comment: Without trying to confuse the user... A pixel is a unit, just not a dimensional unit. But lets leave this discussion for another occasion.

Comment: @Rafael enumarations are not units

Comment: It is a unit of information. :o)

Comment: Just in case someone runs across this in the future. When you use Adobe's _Save for Web_ feature, regardless of product, Adobe removes the DPI (ratio of artificial pixel to human inch unit) from the file. If you read the specification for JPEG/PNG, and compare that to the binary file data, you'll see that's true. Further, when you open a file in Photoshop without DPI, it will always default to 72. That isn't to say it is a 72 DPI file, Photoshop is just giving you a default value to work with. I say this all with a [good amount of experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8245450/231316).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just change the DPI value its just a numeric field in the file metadata, you can do this with nearly any software. Most likely the print company wouldn't care just as long as the pixel count is right.

Anyway, what you should have done is the following:

- since AI designed to design in physical sizes you would take a and make your DOCUMENT in illustrator 4500/300 = 15" by 5700/300=19" then export at 300 PPI.

Comment: Thak you! It's working like that + My computer can do all the operations faster cus currently I have weak PC and workin on smaller image is much faster. Thank you again!